# SQL Server : declare view inside a user-define function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create view inside my function and whenever I would like to create my view I just refer to function and call it.

I wrote this code but I got an error:

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[testFunc]()
RETURNS bigint
AS
BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.r_Sales01_Requests__Duplicates', 'V') IS NOT NULL
       DROP VIEW dbo.r_Sales01_Requests__Duplicates ;
    go

    create view r_Sales01_Requests__Duplicates ( 
     CompanyID
    ,Branch
    ,Year
    ,VoucherType,VoucherNumber
    ,Date_Persian
    ,Row) as
     select 
         CompanyID
        ,Branch
        ,Year
        ,VoucherType
        ,VoucherNumber
        ,Date_Persian
        ,Row
     from t_SalesRequests
     group by CompanyID, Branch, Year, VoucherType, VoucherNumber, Date_Persian, Row
     having count(*)>1

     return 
END
```

Note : The below part is very important for me to have it while creating function .

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.r_Sales01_Requests__Duplicates', 'V') IS NOT NULL
    DROP VIEW dbo.r_Sales01_Requests__Duplicates ;
```

Comment: You won't be able to create a view inside a function (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms191320.aspx). To do so inside a stored procedure you will need to use dynamic SQL. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712702/creating-a-view-using-stored-procedure

Comment: You cannot create sql server objects inside a User define function have a look here to read more about [`Create User-defined Functions Limitations`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms191320.aspx)

Comment: ***WHY*** do you need a function to create the view?!?!? Just **create the view** in SQL Server Management Studio and use it! No point in constantly dropping and re-creating it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions aren't supposed to have side effects.  You can do something like this with a stored procedure:

[Creating a View using stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712702/creating-a-view-using-stored-procedure)