# Viewing Mysql Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I don't know how to call or view the stored procedure, can anyone help me? I have alot of stored procedure here. I don't know how this stored procedure created, i am just editing my supervisor program. Thanks in advance

**UPDATED**

now i know how to call procedure, my problem now is how to create view using stored procedure as reference only

i saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712702/creating-a-view-using-stored-procedure) but it doesn't solve my problem, my problem is create view in existing stored procedure. can anyone help me? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use call function like this

```
call procedure_name(paramater here);
```

Hope this will help